# What are the points 1864 and 1922 on this in-flight map?

Tags: inflight-entertainment

[image: IFE showing map of arrival into Paris from Dubai]

This was taken in a Emirates flight Dubai-Paris in December 2015.

- What are on these 2 locations?
- Why these numbers? Are they dates?

Comment: A picture of the map would help as I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann sorry it took me a while to find a way to compress the image < 2Mb

Comment: It's pretty clear what he's asking. Shouldn't it be closed as offtopic instead?

Comment: @oldmud0 The closed vote were raised before picture uploaded

Comment: better suited for Travel SE?

Comment: Unclear what I am asking, really? Please read my 2 questions which are clearly defined in 2 separate bullet points. Excess of zeal from moderators is a typical issue on SE. The only thing which is a unclear is why they are flagging this function: is it only to gain points?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number may stands for the year of the ships sunk.

1864 may correspond to *[CSS Alabama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Alabama)* (Arabic: ألاباما), a Confederate States Navy Screw sloop which was sunk on June 1864 at the Battle of Cherbourg. The wreck is at [49°45′9″N, 1°41′42″W](https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=CSS_Alabama&params=49_45_9_N_1_41_42_W_).

1922 may correspond to *[SS Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Egypt)* (Arabic: مصر), a British ocean liner which was sunk after a collision with *SS Seine* on 20 May 1922. The wreck is located near [48°10′N, 5°29′W](http://www.plimsoll.org/resources/SCCLibraries/WreckReports2002/20532.asp?view=text).

---

As @mins mention in comment, there are other wrecks appearing on the map in IFE, including *Mary Rose* 1545 near Portsmouth and *San Pedro de Alcantara* 1786 near Peniche.

Comment: Interesting! Do you have any idea why this would appear on the customer screen of a commercial flight?

Comment: @RockScience I don't know. but the map services is usually contract out, not provided by the airlines, and sometimes not even the inflight entertainment system providers themselves.

Comment: Out of interest how did you get to this great answer? Did you translate the Arabic, google and cross-correlate the two numbers, or just have a brainwave?

Comment: @RockScience intuition

Comment: Related on [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/4745535/).